# pandas groupby count string occurrence over column

Tags: python, pandas, count, group-by, dataframe

I want to count the occurrence of a string in a grouped pandas dataframe column.

Assume I have the following Dataframe:

```
catA    catB    scores
A       X       6-4 RET
A       X       6-4 6-4
A       Y       6-3 RET
B       Z       6-0 RET
B       Z       6-1 RET
```

First, I want to group by `catA` and `catB`. And for each of these groups I want to count the occurrence of `RET` in the `scores` column.

The result should look something like this:

```
catA    catB    RET
A       X       1
A       Y       1
B       Z       2
```

The grouping by two columns is easy: `grouped = df.groupby(['catA', 'catB'])`

But what's next?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Call [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply) on the 'scores' column on the [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) object and use the vectorise [`str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) method [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains), use this to filter the `group` and call [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.count.html#pandas.Series.count):

```
In [34]:    
df.groupby(['catA', 'catB'])['scores'].apply(lambda x: x[x.str.contains('RET')].count())

Out[34]:
catA  catB
A     X       1
      Y       1
B     Z       2
Name: scores, dtype: int64
```

To assign as a column use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) so that the aggregation returns a series with it's index aligned to the original df:

```
In [35]:
df['count'] = df.groupby(['catA', 'catB'])['scores'].transform(lambda x: x[x.str.contains('RET')].count())
df

Out[35]:
  catA catB   scores count
0    A    X  6-4 RET     1
1    A    X  6-4 6-4     1
2    A    Y  6-3 RET     1
3    B    Z  6-0 RET     2
4    B    Z  6-1 RET     2
```

Comment: is this then permanently stored in a new column? if not, how can it be stored as a new column?
what i want to do is, that i only want to display the output, if the count is greater than a certain number.

Comment: how can i search for two different strings? so str can contain `RET` or `ASDF`? then I need an RegEx right?

Comment: Use `x.str.contains('RET|ASDF')` also you should post your full requirement, update your question and keep your question to 1 problem per question rather than incrementing your problem

Comment: sorry. i did not know about this requirement when asking the question. it's fine now...