# Pandas Groupby, MultiIndex, Multiple Columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I just worked on creating some columns using .transform() to count some entries.
[I used this reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31649669/pandas-groupby-count-string-occurrence-over-column)

For example:

```
          userID deviceName  POWER_DOWN  USER  LOW_RSSI  NONE  CMD_SUCCESS  
0         24      IR_00          85     0        39     0            0   
1         24      IR_00          85     0        39     0            0   
2         24      IR_00          85     0        39     0            0   
3         24      IR_00          85     0        39     0            0   
4         25     BED_08           0   109        78     0            0   
5         25     BED_08           0   109        78     0            0   
6         25     BED_08           0   109        78     0            0   
7         24      IR_00          85     0        39     0            0   
8         23      IR_09           2     0         0     0            0   
9         23     V33_17           3     0         2     0          134   
10        23     V33_17           3     0         2     0          134   
11        23     V33_17           3     0         2     0          134   
12        23     V33_17           3     0         2     0          134
```

I want to group them by userID and deviceName? 
So that it would look like:

```
          userID deviceName  POWER_DOWN  USER  LOW_RSSI  NONE  CMD_SUCCESS  
0         23      IR_09           2     0         0     0            0
1                V33_17           3     0         2     0          134
2         24      IR_00          85     0        39     0            0
3         25     BED_08           0   109        78     0            0
```

I also want them to be sorted by userID and maybe make userID and deviceName as multi-index.

I tried the `df = df.groupby(['userID', 'deviceName'])`
but returned a 
`<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at0x00000249BBB13DD8>`.
not the dataframe.

By the way, Im sorry. I dont know how to copy a Jupyter notebook In and Out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe need [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(['userID', 'deviceName']).sort_values('userID')
print (df1)
   userID deviceName  POWER_DOWN  USER  LOW_RSSI  NONE  CMD_SUCCESS
8      23      IR_09           2     0         0     0            0
9      23     V33_17           3     0         2     0          134
0      24      IR_00          85     0        39     0            0
4      25     BED_08           0   109        78     0            0
```

If want create `MultiIndex` add [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df1 = (df.drop_duplicates(['userID', 'deviceName'])
         .sort_values('userID')
         .set_index(['userID', 'deviceName']))
print (df1)
                   POWER_DOWN  USER  LOW_RSSI  NONE  CMD_SUCCESS
userID deviceName                                               
23     IR_09                2     0         0     0            0
       V33_17               3     0         2     0          134
24     IR_00               85     0        39     0            0
25     BED_08               0   109        78     0            0
```

Comment: I would also add `df.reset_index()` so that the index has consecutive values.

Comment: @sophros - Yes, if not `MultiIndex` necessary `.set_index()` should be omit.